# Snake moves in vertical block

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a snake game (like the one in old nokia phones) using SpriteKit. The problem is, when the snake's direction changes, the snake moves in a still vertical block, and doesn't get the L-shape (as shown in pic). To get into the context, I have a class named `SKDSpriteNode`, which is the same SKSpriteNode, with an additional `direction` property; the `Snake` class has `direction` and `length` properties. There is a `snakeBody` property, of type `[SKDSpriteNode]`, containing the nodes of the snake body.

Snake's direction is assigned for `.up` when game starts, and then it is assigned by the user's swipe.
And btw, the `changeDirection` methods gets called when snake's direction changes (with `didSet`). Here's the code and the pic:

```
extension ClassicLevelScene {

func startGame() { snake.direction = .up; moveSnake() }

func checkPlacement(for node: SKDSpriteNode) -> SKAction {
    return SKAction.run({
        if !(node.isInsideFrame(of: self)) { self.gameOver() }
    })
}

func getMovement(for node: SKDSpriteNode) -> (once: SKAction, repetitive: SKAction) {
    let movement = SKAction.move(by: node.direction.getVector(withIntensity: movementSpeed), duration: 0.5)
    let moveAction = SKAction.sequence([movement, checkPlacement(for: node)])
    let repetitiveMoveAction = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
    return (moveAction, repetitiveMoveAction)
}

func moveSnake() {
    for node in snakeBody { 
        node.removeAllActions()
        node.run(getMovement(for: node).1) 
    }
}

func moveOnce() {
    for node in snakeBody { 
        node.removeAllActions()
        node.run(getMovement(for: node).0) 
    }
}

func changeDirection() {
    for i in 0..<snake.length {
        if i == 0 {
            snakeBody[i].direction = snake.direction
            snakeBody[i].run(SKAction.move(by: snakeBody[i].direction.getVector(withIntensity: movementSpeed), duration: 0.5))
        } else {
            snakeBody[i].direction = snakeBody[i-1].direction
            snakeBody[i].run(SKAction.move(to: snakeBody[i-1].oldPosition, duration: 0.5))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure why you are doing all of those computed properties in your code, a simple = would suffice

Comment: Okay, I think you're right. I got carried away cz of the need of computed properties in this app

Comment: I really wish I could help you out, but there is so much going on in your code and it is way more complex then it needs to be.  I would focus on cleaning up your code so that it makes better sense.  From what I can tell, you are adding a lot of actions, and you never show how direction is calculated, and either of those could be causing problems

Comment: I'll edit in a sec

Comment: That happens because you set the direction of all pieces of snake to the same thing, in your else.

Comment: @James how can i assign the direction continuously?

Comment: At a guess, do `snakeBody[i].direction = snakeBody[i - 1].direction`.  however if you do that the next segment will also turn unless you iterate the array backwards.  Really, moving the snake means cut a square off the tail, and stick it on the head.  You might have better luck with that approach,

Comment: the only part of your snake that should have an action is the head

Comment: @James I'll try, especially that soon, the head will be replaced by a real head-shaped node

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but how would the body move??

Comment: the body should just follow the head, so `bodypart.position = previousBodyPart.lastPosition` (This is pseudocode)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I made something that resembles what u suggested, plz check the edited code. But it's not correctly working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to post as an answer to show you code,  but you should be only moving the head, and let the tail drag behind.  Now there are better ways to do this, but for simplicity with code you have already written, here is what it should look like

```
extension ClassicLevelScene {

    func startGame() { snake.direction = .up; moveSnake() }

    func checkPlacement(for node: SKSpriteNode) -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.run({
            if !(node.isInsideFrame(of: self)) { self.gameOver() }
        })
    }

    func getMovement(for node: SKDSpriteNode) -> (once: SKAction, repetitive: SKAction) {
        let movement = SKAction.move(by: node.direction.getVector(withIntensity: movementSpeed), duration: 0.5)
        let moveTail = SKAction.run({self.moveTail()})
        let moveAction = SKAction.sequence([movement, moveTail,checkPlacement(for: node)])
        let repetitiveMoveAction = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
        return (moveAction, repetitiveMoveAction)
    }

    func moveTail()
    {
        for i in 1..<snake.length {
                snakeBody[i].direction = snakeBody[i-1].direction
                snakeBody[i].position = snakeBody[i-1].oldPosition
        }
    }

    func moveSnake() {
        let head = snakeBody[0] { 
            head.removeAllActions()
            head.run(getMovement(for: head).1) 
        }
    }

    func moveOnce() {
        let head = snakeBody[0] { 
            head.removeAllActions()
            head.run(getMovement(for: head).0) 
        }
    }

    func changeDirection() {
            let head = snakeBody[0] { 
            head.removeAllActions()
            head.direction = snake.direction
            head.run(SKAction.move(by:  head.direction.getVector(withIntensity: movementSpeed), duration: 0.5))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That code didn't work, but the idea of the other parts moving helped. I finally found a way to do it.